# How to extract packages from Fedora live CD?

Tags: fedora, desktop-environment, lxde

I wanted to install the lxde desktop environment from the Fedora spin live CD on my virtual machine. Initially I tried to set up the local repo. YUM is able to find the local repo but it's not able to find the package lxde.

[image]

Unsure if I did the setup wrong or I am not suppose to install RPM packages from a live CD. It occurred to me that I might need to extract the packages from the live CD instead, can anyone please confirm if it's right to use YUM to install from the live CD or I need to extract the RPM packages from the live CD.

Answer (score 0):

You can install packages using the built-in installer while using live media. Yum is now deprecated so go with dnf. Try

```
su -c 'dnf group install lxde-desktop'
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not able to find the package

Warning: Group 'lxde-desktop' does not exist

Comment: just had a look at the content of the iso file, there appears to be no packages folder, could that be that reason?

Comment: There are no packages on a live cd. A live cd is one big compressed image of the author´s OS install. However you can install the live cd to a hard disk, or usb, and rebuild a package with `rpmrebuild` http://rpmrebuild.sourceforge.net/ ...